# A midrule line under each column, separated by white space

Tags: tables, booktabs, hline

How can we draw a horizontal line in a table with white space between each column?

A MWE, using `booktabs`'s `\midrule` and `\cmidrule`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
    Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3\\
    \midrule %Can we make a gap between each column
    Body 1 & Body 2 & Body 3\\
    \cmidrule{2-2} \cmidrule{3-3} %Can we make a gap between these two cmidrules ... or something similar using \cmidrule{2-3}
    Body 4 & Body 5 & Body 5\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

The end result should look something like this: [image: Mock-up example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\cmidrule` has options for make line shorter. for example with `(r)` is shorter on the right side, with `(l)` on the left side and `(lr)` on the both side. for more details see documentation for the `booktabs` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
    Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3\\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(r){2-2} \cmidrule{3-3} 
    Body 1 & Body 2 & Body 3\\
    \cmidrule(r){2-2} \cmidrule{3-3} 
    Body 4 & Body 5 & Body 5\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]